# Jquery set width of table on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like this..

```
<table id="content" style ="border:none>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table  id="content_medium" style ="width:100%">
                        <tr class="grid_heading">
                            <th class="student">Students</th>
                            <th class="year">Year</th>
                            <th class="group">Roll Group</th>
                            <th class="Type">Session</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

How can I change the width of table using jquery.. I have button which when clicked should add width 100% and should remove width attribute when clicked next time..

Like?

```
function openpartialView() {
            $(".content").addcss("width","100%");
    }
function closepartialView() {
            $(".content").removecss("width", "100%");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few extra quotes, you can change it to:

```
<button id="tblsize">Change Size </button>
<table id="content" style ="border:none">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table  id="content_medium" style="width:100%" >
                        <tr class="grid_heading">
                            <th class="student">Students</th>
                            <th class="year">Year</th>
                            <th class="group">Roll Group</th>
                            <th class="Type">Session</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

create CSS class:

```
.changeWidth{
    width: 100%;
}
```

and finally use:

```
$("#tblsize").click(function() {
   $("#content").toggleClass("changeWidth");
});
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/xrEhB/)

Answer (score 5):

A flexible solution is to dynamically add/remove classes instead of styling.

JS:

```
$("#content").addClass('fullwidth');
$("#content").removeClass('fullwidth');
```

CSS:

```
.fullwidth{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in two way

1: change css property

```
function openpartialView() 
{
   $("#content").css("width","100%");
}

function closepartialView() 
{
    $("#content").css("width", "0%");
}
```

2: Make an one class in css and dynamic add/remove class

```
function openpartialView() 
{
   $("#content").addClass("tabwidth");
}

function closepartialView() 
{
    $("#content").removeClass("tabwidth");
}
```

CSS:

```
.tabwidth{
       width: 100%;
    }
```

Let me know is this helpfull?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

At First you have an `id` as `content` not `class` so use `#` instead of `.` in `selecter`

```
function openpartialView() {
    $("#content").width("100%");
}
function closepartialView() {
    $("#content").width('');
    //you can use  $(".content").removeAttr('style');
}
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/width